# DeTr Saving and Exporting Custom Trained Model

Tags: google-colaboratory, object-detection, detection, pytorch-lightning

files i downloaded after training the model :

1. config.json
2. model.safetensors
3. logs > hparams/yaml ( empty file )
4. logs > events.out.tfevents.1707970167.d4c7dd713d7a.235.0
5. logs > checkpoint > output.ckpt

---

The following code was used to save :

```
MODEL_PATH = 'custom-model'
model.model.save_pretrained(MODEL_PATH)
```

---

The custom-model folder contains the file number 1&2 (config.json and model.safetensors)

when i try to load the model which was custom-trained by me in the same session of google colab it works fine , **but** when the same folder is copied to another colab notebook and tried to execute , it throws this error :

```
/data does not appear to have a file named preprocessor_config.json
```

---

this code is used to load the custom model

```
CHECKPOINT = 'models/data'

image_processor = DetrImageProcessor.from_pretrained(CHECKPOINT)
model = DetrForObjectDetection.from_pretrained(CHECKPOINT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so the problem was in this line

```
image_processor = DetrImageProcessor.from_pretrained(CHECKPOINT)
```

replaced the CHECKPOINT with `'facebook/detr-resnet-50'`

complete code for loading the model

```
CHECKPOINT = 'models/data'

image_processor = DetrImageProcessor.from_pretrained('facebook/detr-resnet-50') 
model = DetrForObjectDetection.from_pretrained(CHECKPOINT)
```

and the models/data contains all the **files ( 1-5 )** mentioned in the above question